# My Launch Configurations are not being added to the Launch Configuration Type I created

Tags: eclipse

My question goes here......

My job is to create a new Launch Configuration Type in Eclipse and add some Launch Configurations to the type I created.

I created a new Launch Configuration Type by extending the extension point **org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes**

To add Launch Configurations to the type I created, I came to know that I need to extend the extension point **org.eclipse.debug.core.launchDelegates**. The only method that is to be overridden if it is extended is the launch() method. I placed the following code in this method.

```
public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode,
        ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

ILaunchConfigurationType type = configuration.getType();//to get the type I created

ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy workingCopy = type.newInstance(null, "MyConfiguration");

workingCopy.setAttribute(ATTR_MAIN_TYPE_NAME, "Mainclass");
workingCopy.setAttribute(ATTR_PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS, "start");

}
```

The problem is that the launch configurations that are created as mentioned above are not listed in the run/debug configuration dialog in the eclipse and also that it is not entering the launch() method body (founded it by debugging).

This is what I did to create launch configurations under a launch configuration type. if this is not enough please provide me with the required information.

These are the materials I have gone through
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html and
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html

Thanks in advance..........